# unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred while using 2 include in a EF query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, include

I added the second Include to my EF query

```
return entities.lnkAnimalSubCategories.Where(t => t.tblVersie.Naam.Equals(webVersie)).Include("tblAnimalSubCategorie").Include("tblStal").ToList();
```

and I got this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred in Unknown Module.Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Does anyone know why I am having this error?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow; please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This error occurs when I am used 2 "Include". with just one, it works fine but I needed to load both related entities ("tblAnimalSubCategorie" and "tblStal")

Comment: that isn't enough information. what version of entity framework? what database provider, etc?

Comment: I am using EF6 and sql server

Answer (score -1):

The problem was : Json could not handle circular object references.
To fix that, I added the following code in Global.asax

`var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Array;`